# Music player with volume control separate from Android main volume

Tags: android, music, media-player, volume-control

Let's say I'm listening to text to speech audio from an Android app. I want to have some low volume instrumental music playing at the same time in another app. (Both apps allow simultaneous playback.)

The problem is that the music is too loud, and makes it difficult to hear what is being spoken by the text to speech. If I try to turn the volume of my current music player down, the whole Android system audio will be turned down, including the text to speech. Obviously, this defeats the purpose.

Therefore, I'm looking for a music player for Android which has its own volume control, one which will not affect the main Android volume.

Comment: Underlying issue, for those interested: [Set different volume for multiple apps running at the same time](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/92530/16575) is not possible using a 3rd app (or built-in to Android) due to the way the Android sound system is designed. // Fiksdal: While waiting for matching recommendations, be welcome to check with my app list on [Jukeboxes and more](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/multimedia_music_jukeboxen). It might not been outlined/annotated in the list itself, but at least it makes checking easier and narrows down the list of candidates.

Comment: Speaking of which, here are some candidates you should check for it: [Maven](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.maven.blueplayer) has a built-in mixer, as do [PlayerPro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tbig.playerprotrial), [PowerAmp](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.maxmpz.audioplayer) and [Rocket](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jrtstudio.AnotherMusicPlayer). I'm not using any of them myself, so I cannot really rate them (and make it an answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

Download mxplayer, go to settings menu, select audio and enable audio player and disable the system volume so that it will not synchronize with system media volume.

Now you can listen to audio novel with some background music.

Answer (score 0):

use discord....in miui 10 you can u listen to programs with deafalt music volume panel and discord music with ringtone volume panel. for that u need a mi phone and discord installed on u phone and in the discord u need to be in a channel and after creating a channel u need to add a music bot in the channel. u can play music from youtube

Comment: and can this be implemented without discord in miui? I do not need gamer's chat, I need volume control for all apps

Answer (score 0):

I've been using this tabata app. It has a setting to change the volume of your music files so it won't affect the main volume. Works great for me! https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.slydroid.watch